# Get User Name from Google Plus in android

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I have integrated Google plus with my android app. Everything is working fine, i am also connected to Google plus but I am not able to get the name of current user logged.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    String personName="Unknown";
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
        Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    }
}
```

`Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` this method always return **null**.

Any help will appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have look on this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people

Comment: String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl(); add this line

Comment: Are you missing a `}` from the `if (Plus....)` statement?

Comment: } this bracket is missed while pasting code here.

Comment: @ Anjali, thank for replying. As i am getting currentPerson null, i can't call getUrl. it will gives Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: I just noticed that Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) returned Email id of signed in user, but Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) returned null.

Comment: I still can't make it work. But using  Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient) instead of PeopleApi, getting email address of signed in account.

Comment: instead having correct sha1 Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)  always return null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add this line:

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
```

Like this:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    /* This Line is the key */
    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);

    String personName="Unknown";
    if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
       Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
       personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
       .........
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , save from execution. but why on earth no one mention this is so important :(, thankyou again

Comment: been looking for this all day, and even the QuickStart sample for G+ login provided by Google has the NullPointerException at onConnected. What a shame ?

Comment: i am using onconnected inside a fragment and setResultCallback(this); can't resolve 'this'. How can I solve this?

Comment: @deepak probably it's too late , but one way to do it is to make it: setResultActivityCallback(getActivity()); if you do need to handle the callback inside the fragment not in the hosting activity, you can call onActivityResult for your fragment from withing the activity

Answer (score 10):

For me the cause of this call returning null was that the Google+ API Was not enabled for my application. Navigate to https://console.developers.google.com, select your project and enable the Google+ API to get it working!

Comment: I can't believe I missed something so simple I had enabled the google + domain api.

Comment: I had the same problem.
I also can't believe that I missed such a simple concept of first enabling the Google Plus api.

Comment: I enabled this and did the step above, and it's still not working for me? :(

Answer (score 5):

In my case the null returned because I have added that line:

addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
            //.addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
            .build();
```

================= UPDATE ========================
Scopes should be set as below:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

Comment: Along with the aove solution, All you need to make sure is, have a credentials added in Google API console with OAuth.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you generated both of debug and production Client ID by SHA1 keystores.
It display in **APIs & Auth** -> **Credentials** tab of your [project](https://console.developers.google.com).

[Setting up OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#generatingoauth2) for Android documentation says:

> In a terminal, run the Keytool utility to get the SHA1 fingerprint for your digitally signed .apk file's public certificate.
>
> ...example for debug-keystore...
>
> Important: When you prepare to release your app to your users, follow these steps again and create a new OAuth 2.0 client ID for your production app. For production apps, use your own private key to sign the production app's .apk file.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a lot of approaches but I was still facing the same issue. Finally, in app build.gradle file, I found that my applicationId was not same as the package name in Credentials. I fixed that and everything worked like a charm.

Thus, make sure:

- applicationId in build.gradle
- package name in AndroidManifest.xml
- package name in Credentials

are all same.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: solved, In my case **applicationId** and **Manifest package name** was different.