# installing google-services.json config file in IntelliJ gradle project? Google sign-in support

Tags: android, intellij-idea, oauth, google-api

I am attempting to get Google Sign-in support for my Android application.  I have created a client api and signature based on the documentation (at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), and generated a google-services.json file.  However, I get stuck at this line in the documentation.

> Add the configuration file to your project
>
> Copy the google-services.json file you just downloaded into the app/ or mobile/ directory of your Android Studio project. Open the Android Studio Terminal pane:
>
> MAC/LINUXWINDOWS
> $ mv path-to-download/google-services.json app/

I am using IntelliJ + Gradle rather than Android Studio, so there is no app/ or mobile/ folder and thus no idea where I am supposed to put this file.  It seems a necessary prerequisite, so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: how does your project structure look like? `app` is the default name of the android module folder.

Comment: `<git-repo>
- .gradle
- .idea
- build
- <app-name>
   - build
   - libs
   - src
      - androidTest
      - main
      - production
      - staging
   - build.gradle`

Comment: put the json file inside <application name> folder :)

Comment: ok, cool :).  Not sure how to tell if it's working, though, as I still fail to get gplus login to work, i.e.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22532412/get-user-name-from-google-plus-in-android